# How do I set cloudfront signed cookies when its a different domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I am looking into using aws cloudfront with signed cookies to serve static protected content on my webpage. AWS documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-setting-signed-cookie-canned-policy.html) says we should set 3 cookies which should be passed those to our cloudfront urls (images/css/html/js/etc). Its not clear how do to this as cloudfront will be a separate domain than the one which served the page.

***mywebsite.com*** will server a page which has links to static CDN content on ***mycloudfrontsubdomain.cloudfront.net*** and should pass the signed cookies to gain access. How do I set cookies on ***cloudfront.net*** from my own domain or is there some way AWS can do this for you. Im not great with front end web development (Im mostly backend) but my understanding is we cant set cookies for a different domain that did not serve up the current page. I would assume AWS has some endpoint we could call to have cloudfront set cookies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloudfront supports alternate domain names.

For example, you can set your Cloudfront distribution to have an alternate domain name of ***mycloudfrontsubdomain.mywebsite.com***. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/LinkFormat.html#LinkFormat_OwnDomain

Now you can set a cookie from ***mywebsite.com*** with a domain of ***mywebsite.com***. Cookie with that domain will also include all subdomains (so also including cloudfront). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#attributes

Comment: Thanks. I decided to go with purely signed urls but makes sense what you are saying. Not going to set up a subdomain since i would have to ask our dev ops team to update our cname records i think. Giving credit for the answer without verifying as it would surely work

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply! Another question comes to mind, how to configure the cloud front distribution when working locally. For example, the team that develops the front end often works on the URL https://localhost:8080. How can we set the signed cookies in this case?

Comment: You can't. Cookies can't be set from one domain to another, it's a security risk and browsers will block the attempt. I suggest your dev team to also use domain names and https for their local environment. You can force a domain name to reroute to localhost in your hosts file, you can use mkcert to make yourself a CA and generate SSL certs and you can use a reverse proxy like nginx or apache to locally handle rerouting domain name to a localhost:3000 application. (NOTE: When running front end on Node, you'd have to supply CA cert to Node separately with an env variable)

Comment: on localhost the hosts file is your best friend. If you are on linux its /etc/hosts - on windows its in /windows/system32/drivers/hosts . This file can be used to override dns settings which is really useful for development. You add an entry like 127.0.0.1 dummydomain.com and if you type the domain in your browser it will actually resolve to your localhost. You could also set up local self signed certs if you want to run https.